# driver.find_element_by_xpath - trying to retreive the text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Here is my element in an html page

```
<div class='test'>my text</div>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the text of this div with my selenium driver in python

```
mytext = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'test')/text()]")
print mytext
```

but nothing is returned

Thank you

```
this returns "True" :
try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='test']")
        mystatus = "True"
except NoSuchElementException:
        mystatus = "False"
```

but this returns "False"

```
try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='test']/text()")
        mystatus = "True"
except NoSuchElementException:
        mystatus = "False"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the text after you have the element with `.text` in Python.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='test']").text
```

Comment: That's it - awesome, thanks !

Comment: Glad it worked! Go ahead and mark this as the correct response if it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Slight adjustment:

`//div[contains(@class, 'test')]/text()`

You just had the closing square bracket in the wrong place.